# Run same script "infinite" times

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script that does random calculation and prints it, but now I need these results written in a text file. I edited it and now each time I execute this script, new results are appended in a text file. However, I need as many new results as I can get into the same text file, so is there a way to make it run again and again (and stop it when I want to by keyboard interrupt)?

I could do something like:

```
    inf_loop=0
    while inf_loop==0:
        #code to append to text file
```

But the script is rather long, thus I need to have each line within the loop indented properly.

Comment: What's wrong with indenting a line? Put your code that produces some results in a function, then `while True: call_function()`.... ?

Comment: Code is around 150 lines, if i need to add a while loop, or put it in a function, I need to edit each line, adding blank spaces before each.

Comment: What kind of editor/IDE are you using that doesn't allow you to just select the entire file, then hit tab and indent the whole lot for you...?

Comment: Even manually indenting each of the 150 lines surely would have been faster than typing out a question and waiting for an answer

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment so I'm gonna say my opinion here.

`tab` is your friend here. If you're using Python IDLE, just select all the lines and hit `Tab`. If you wanna outdent, try `shift + tab`.

Comment: same in pydev for eclipse, and Anaconda's Spyder. So I think its safe to assume any decent python IDE will indent lines when highlighting and hitting tab.

Comment: I've actually never seen or used an IDE that *couldn't* do this

Comment: @TimCastelijns, yep! But what i mean is that if one's using something like Vim, there will be more options and flexibility :D

Answer (score 0):

If indenting is a problem for you and you really want to hack this down, you could simply restart your script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

# your script content

args=['some_name']
os.execlp('./your_script.py',*args)
```

Run the script from the directory it is located in. If you need to pass arguments, simply append them to `args`.

If your script finishes it will restart itself again and again...

Answer (score 0):

If you're adamant that you don't want to change your existing script, create a new one, then keep calling the other...

```
while True:
    execfile('/path/to/other/script.py')
```

Although you should really be putting the work of the other script into a function, then repeatedly calling that instead of the script...

```
while True:
    call_your_function()
```